# Where to sell metals with numismatic value

Tags: gold, coins, precious-metals, silver

I have various silver and gold bars and coins. After getting quotes for my collection from a local coin shop, I noticed that the bullion values are reasonable, but for rare coins, the quote is far lower than the actual value of the coins.

In the case of e.g. **American Eagle 1oz Silver Proof** coins, these are selling from the [US MINT](https://catalog.usmint.gov/american-eagle-2019-one-ounce-silver-proof-coin-19EA.html?&cm_mmc=Google-_-PLA%20-%20Non-Brand-_-PLA%20-%20Non-Brand-_-19EA&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIp5eW7rDZ5wIVC9VkCh2WHgNKEAYYAiABEgIfBPD_BwE) at $55/each, and I paid around $50 for these several years ago. The coins are perfect and untouched...

***Where/how can one sell coins at (or closer to) the value that the US MINT offers?***

Comment: In what sense are the offers lower than the value of the coins? Something's value is almost by definition equal to what someone will offer you for it. It sounds like you may have paid substantially over the coins value.

Comment: @Vality If that were true, then why would the US Mint waste their time and money advertising coins for the price I mentioned.

Comment: @JavoblRR mostly collectors who want them for sentimental or collection purposes, not speculators who want to speculate on the price of the underlying metal. They mostly purchase bullion which as you have noticed has a much more lively resale market.

Comment: "but for rare coins, the quote is far lower than the actual value of the coins."  This is why I **always** buy secondary market and off-brand stuff (like APMEX instead of PAMP Suisse).

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense

Comment: @Vality: I don't see how a coin having much higher value to collectors than the intrinsic value associated with its component metal(s) invalidates the question.  He's asking how to participate in the secondary market of collectors.

Comment: @Vality Seems like the issue is he's trying to sell to the wrong buyer. The metal guy is going to pay what the metal's worth. He needs to find a coin guy.

Comment: Sorry, you're not the US MINT, you'll have a hard time selling for "retail value". I can get a [1987 one for $53](https://www.apmex.com/product/1086/1987-s-1-oz-proof-silver-american-eagle-w-box-coa). That coin *might* become monetarily valuable to great grandchildren someday. As it stands take this as a lesson in speculation and supply-and-demand. I hope you didn't buy in bulk.

Comment: Is this really the US Mint with a domain that ends in .GOV?  There are several private mints who work really hard to make people think they are official.  They market very aggressively to less experienced collectors, promising collectible value but of course not guaranteeing it, and they produce so much they swamp the market.  It's functionally a scam, but technically legal.

Comment: I am slightly confused by the question about the coins. Suppose you were a buyer who wished to own a particular coin and you had two sellers: the mint, a government agency guaranteed to give you exactly what you're paying for, and a random stranger off the street who may be attempting to defraud you. Why would you, the buyer, be willing to pay the same amount to both potential sellers? I would think that the seller who may be attempting to defraud me would sell at a steep discount to offset that risk.  Can you explain?

Comment: The certificate validated the coin itself

Comment: I am slightly confused by your comment about certificates. Suppose you were a buyer who wished to own a particular coin *that came with a certificate*. Again, there are two sellers, one who guarantees you that the coin and certificate are genuine, and one who may be attempting to defraud you. Would you be willing to pay the same amount to both sellers, or would you want the seller who may have a fraudulent certificate to offer a discount over the service provided by the guaranteed seller?

Comment: Not the same, but a closer amount. I think the coin show vs coin shop environment is what I found useful from the answers.

Comment: The certificate is meaningless. The bottom line is, you bought $18 worth (at today's price) of silver for $50 because it had a pretty design stamped on it. This isn't even claimed to be "rare" or a "limited edition". The makers will churn out as many as people are prepared to buy. $30 profit for $20 materials and manufacturing costs is a good business deal - for them, not for you.

Comment: @JacobIRR: OK, so what you are saying then is that if you were a buyer, you'd be willing to buy something from the mint for $55, or from some random stranger for $50. This makes sense, because that is what you did. So now lets keep going. Suppose you are buying this coin not because you like it, but because you run a shop and you intend to sell it to someone else *at a higher price* later. Now how much are you willing to pay that random stranger? Keep in mind that in order to sell it later, you'll need to price it at below-mint costs.

Comment: @EricLippert "I know what a surplus is"

Comment: precious-metals + coins = disappointment. I had to look up *numismatic*. My definition is, *not worth the paper it's printed on*.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what this question is really asking; it sounds like you're asking "*I paid the highest price a reasonable person would pay a stranger for this item; where can I find someone who will pay me more?*" The question answers itself when phrased like that: you won't find a reasonable person who pays more than the highest price a reasonable person would pay.

Comment: Where did I say more? I said "at (or closer to)".

Comment: Turns out my original vendor was able to do a buyback at a much closer rate to what I originally paid, so I'm going with that so I can switch over to the bullion side of metals.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What do the coins go for on eBay compared to what the coin shop is offering?  I wouldn't expect to be able to resell a non-graded, recent coin like this at the retail price the mint offers.  The mint focuses on sales to collectors who get some enjoyment out of their coin collection, not investors looking to resell their collections at a profit.

If the dealer's offer is substantially below the fair market value on something like eBay, it could be worth it to sell your coins there or at a coin show.  I would expect, though, that the hassle of selling the coins yourself is going to outweigh the cut the dealer is taking.

Comment: I've had my best luck on ebay.

Answer (score 11):

The best opportunity to sell small amounts of collectible coins is to go to coin shows.

Now the gold and silver coins from the U.S. Mint catalog-website are not bullion but are mint-marked coins.

Comment: But note that the "collectable coins" here might be like for instance cars: you can buy a new car for $X from the dealer, but good luck getting more than a fraction of that when you try to sell it.  In this case, the price of the coins is set by the US Mint, not the free market (as with actual collectible coins).

Comment: The mint has no way of placing the mint-marked silver, gold, or platinum coins but can only offer them.

Comment: @S Spring: I think that's what I said.  The mint offers the coins at prices that (apparently) are well above their real value in a free market, knowing that some people are, for whatever reason, willing to pay that price.  Unfortunately, it seems from the OP's post that one reason some people buy them is that they have a mistaken idea of their true market value.

Comment: The mint sells mint-marked special-issue coins to the free market. Coins dealers sell the special-issue coins, at a profit, to buyers who missed the mint's offering time period. Mint-marked special-issue coins are known to rise in value and keep up with inflation even if they are not otherwise scarce. Now someone might make a mistake of selling a special-issue mint-market precious-metal coin for bullion value.

Comment: @S Spring: I think you misunderstand what is meant by a free market.  The US mint is a monopoly, and one with the power to enforce its monopoly through legal sanctions.  That is, anyone who tried to produce those coins and sell them at a lower price ( Google says silver is currently going for $18.41/oz, so it should be profitable) could be charged with counterfeiting.  While I know nothing about collectable coin values, the OP states that he can't sell his for anywhere near what he paid.